# Angualr2 Error : Cannot set property value of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter

Tags: angular

Form looks something like:

```
    <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="update()">

                <ion-label floating>First Name</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" id="fname" [ngFormControl]="fname"> 

   </form>
```

Associated class:

```
export class ProfilePage {
    myForm: ControlGroup;
    fname: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private _profile: Profile, fb: FormBuilder)  {

        this.myForm = fb.group({
            'fname': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), firstCharacter])]
        });

        this.fname = this.myForm.controls['fname'];


        Promise.all([this._profile.firstname, this._profile.lastname, this._profile.base64Image]).then(values => {
            this.fname.value = values[0];
         //   this.lname.value = values[1];

        });
    }
```

Error received:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property value of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you should use setValue or patchValue methods of FormGroup.

```
this.myForm.patchValue({fname: firstName});
```

use patchValue if you want to selectively update only certain fields, or setValue and update all

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(this.fname as Control).updateValue(values[0]);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13252270)

Comment: I wanted to provide an answer, not a critique. From my understanding, he's trying to update the value of the form control, but `this.fname.value = newValue` is not the right way to so, so I suggested another way to achieve his task.

Comment: Then please elaborate more. For example, you can simply move your comment to this answer.