# angular 4 unit test issue - I want to set a form FormControl fields value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, testbed

I'm having trouble setting the value of a FormControl field called searchUser in my unit test.

In the below code "this.searchUser.value" is a form control.
So in my test I did this so I could set it but didnt work:

```
homeComponent.searchUser = new FormControl();
homeComponent.searchUser.value = "ste";
```

**This is the component method I'm testing (mapUsers):**

```
mapUsers(users: User[]): User[] {
    let results: User[] = [];

    users.forEach((user: User) => {
      let name = user.name.toLowerCase();
      if (name.includes(this.searchUser.value.toLowerCase())) results.push(user);      
    });

    return results; 
  }
```

**This is my full unit test spec:**

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { HomeModule } from "./home.module";
import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";
import { HighlightDirective } from "../../directives/highlight.directive";

describe("HomeComponent", () => {
  let userService;
  let homeComponent;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HomeModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      providers: [
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler,
        UserService
      ]
    })
  });

  beforeEach(inject([UserService], service => {
    userService = service;
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    homeComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  it("should return array of users", async(() => {
    // Arrange
    const mockUsers: User[] = [{"name": "Steven"}];
    homeComponent.searchUser = new FormControl();
    homeComponent.searchUser.value = "ste";

    // Act
    const mockResponse = homeComponent.mapUsers(mockUsers);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // Assert
    expect(mockResponse).toEqual(mockUsers);
  }));

});
```

**Karma error I get:**

> Failed: Cannot set property value of [object Object] which has only a
>   getter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angualr2 Error : Cannot set property value of #<AbstractControl> which has only a getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810174/angualr2-error-cannot-set-property-value-of-abstractcontrol-which-has-only)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot directly set value of a form.You have to use either patchValue or setValue method like this

```
homeComponent.searchUser.patchValue({[formControlName]:[formControlValue]})
```

Comment: Do you mean like this in my case: homeComponent.searchUser.patchValue({["searchUser"]:["ste"]})

Comment: @AngularM no, that makes no sense syntactically; it would be a computed property name and an array value. The brackets are to indicate placeholders, I think.

Comment: patchvalue and setvalue is available on form instance not on formcontrol 
forminstance means created using either formbuilder or using new FormGroup()

Comment: yes brackets are placeholders in patchvalue method you pass the object with keys as the formcontrol name and value as the formcontrol value